# Есть ли в БД новые данные

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Можно ли как-то проверить были ли добавлены новые элементы в БД FirebaseDatabse?
Я делаю чат и мне нужно выводить пользователю уведомление "Вам пришло новое сообщение" тогда, когда кто-то написал сообщение. Так как у меня все сообщения хранятся в БД, то я предполагаю,что нужно как-то проверять постоянно БД на добавление новых элементов. Если добавились новые элементы,следовательно кто-то прислал сообщение. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можете хранить в приложении последний полученный индекс сообщения, и периодически делать запрос-проверку, какой индекс сейчас самый новый на сервере.

Comment: @Kromster Я вас не понял и не представляю как это можно сделать с Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону [ChildEvenListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) - там есть метод `onChildAdded()`

Comment: Может вы подскажите метод,который позволит посчитать количество дочерних объектов в базе данных?

Comment: Один пост - один вопрос